# How to select other row of data in access database using Visual Basic?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, database-connection

I am new to programming so don't be too harsh.

The situation is like this:

I want get the values from access database and return it to a textbox in visual basic. I tried these codes but the problem is, it is always returning the data in the first row only. I want to get the data from ID = 4. This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdshow_Click()

    strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where ID = '4' "

    With RS

    txtstudent.Text = !Student
    txtage.Text = !Age

   End With

End Sub
```

The access database is like this:

http://postimg.org/image/mrtcmsc3b/

I know that my codes are wrong. The only thing that I know is that I must return the value from database and assign it to a variable and place it in the textbox. I know how the program goes but I dont know the right codes that will work.

Your response will be fully appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Open your project and find that `Sub`. Now scroll to the top of the module (e.g., by hitting [Ctrl-Home]) and look for a statement (line) that says `Option Explicit`. If you don't see one, add that line at the very top of the module. Then try running your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have omitted some of your code, the code you are showing is not actually doing anything to get the recordset. You are assigning a query to a variable, but then you are not using that variable. For instance, where are you actually opening your recordset? The syntax for the ADO recordset *Open* statement is: *recordset.Open Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options*
 **Source** is an optional argument that in your case would be your SQL statement, so your method should look more like below.

```
Private Sub cmdshow_Click()

    strsql1 = "select * from Table1 where ID = 4"

    RS.Open strsql1
    With RS

        txtstudent.Text = !Student
        txtage.Text = !Age

    End With

End Sub
```

You can read the full documentation here, [Open Method (ADO Recordset)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also there is an error in the SQL statement yourself. You surrounded **4** with single quotes indicating it is a string, where in the screen shots of your table it appears to be numeric. And take Gord Thompson's suggestion to heart. The `Option Explicit` statement will save you many headaches by requiring you to declare all your variables. If you haven't already done so go to the **Tools | Options** menu and on the **Editor** tab make sure **Require Variable Declaration** is checked.